# how to check if i am having correct file at laravel controller from post request

Tags: php, laravel, upload, xmlhttprequest

trying to upload an image at laravel:
 On `echo $request;` i am getting this:
 `POST /infoshore0/api/public/v1/product/addProductImg?lang=en-us HTTP/1.1 Accept: application/json, text/plain, */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: en-IN,en-GB;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7 Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLNjc0MTcsIm5iZiI6MTYwMjI2MzgxNywianRpIjoiZmxhdHJ1Mk5BeGdLc0JWRCJ9.lFcZOOSZx_94eZY97L-OfR36XLX_KLqvbZFJo5l2FW8 Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 209141 Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8 Cookie: laravel_session=7dab0a4fdba93fbec911f Host: localhost:8080 Origin: http://localhost:8080 Referer: http://localhost:8080/cp/ Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36 {"file":"ÿØÿà\u0000\u00.......very long text","product_id":499859489}`

 I have tried `if ($request->hasFile('file')) { echo 'File Found'; }` and nithing is happening
Also 
 Passing product_id and image  file using angularJS

Comment: What is your exact question? Do you want to know if request has file? Or do you want to know if the file is of image or other docs?

Comment: hi yes, i want check if the request has image file. using POST to send image from angularJS and also, i can see the image string (which is very very long) when i echo $request

Comment: What does "nothing is working" mean? What exactly have you tried (show us the code), what were you hoping would happen, and what happened instead (show us some exact output). Click [edit] and add these details, don't try to post them as comments.

Comment: Are your trying to determine file from API request?

Comment: can you post us `dd($request);` Instead of echo

Comment: Did you try ***dd($request->all())*** ??

Comment: its a plain text request (that looks like JSON) ... how is it supposed to know that inside that plain text is JSON and one of those properties you are trying to say is the contents of a file?

Comment: dd($request->all() and dd($request) is giving me an empty array.